# How can I make my node program block when I drop in a repl?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm just diving into ember addons and node so this is probably a bit of a newb question. I'm also coming from a rails/lisp background so I love dropping a repl into my code to poke around at run-time. I've tried using node's `repl` but it seems like it's not blocking and the program is running to completion.

#### Setup

I'm trying to run an ember generator for an addon:

```
ember g addon test-addon
```

which is failing with this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  at Class.module.exports.generateBowerJson (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/blueprints/addon/index.js:62:33)
  at Class.module.exports.files (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/blueprints/addon/index.js:108:10)
  at Class.Blueprint.supportsAddon (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/blueprint.js:783:15)
  at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/generate-from-blueprint.js:25:98)
  at Class.module.exports.Command.extend.run (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/generate.js:79:17)
  at Class.<anonymous> (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:136:17)
  at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:489:16)
  at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:501:17)
  at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:472:11)
  at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1290:9)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I look in `node_modules/ember-cli/blueprints/addon/index.js` and find where I think the problem is. So, I add this code hoping to get a repl with the prompt `hi>`:

```
var replServer = repl.start({
  prompt: 'hi >',
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
}).on('exit', function() {
  delete contents.private;
  contents.name = this.project.name();

  ^ this seems to be the problem
  rest of original code ...
```

But, when I run `ember g addon test-addon` again, it just blows by the prompt and the program exists with the same error:

```
$ember g addon test-addon
version: 0.2.5
hi >Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  at Class.module.exports.generateBowerJson (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/blueprints/addon/index.js:58:33)
  at Class.module.exports.files (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/blueprints/addon/index.js:104:10)
  at Class.Blueprint.supportsAddon (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/blueprint.js:783:15)
  at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/generate-from-blueprint.js:25:98)
  at Class.module.exports.Command.extend.run (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/generate.js:79:17)
  at Class.<anonymous> (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:136:17)
  at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:489:16)
  at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:501:17)
  at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:472:11)
  at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/dixon/ember-cli/todo-mvc/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1290:9)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is a "repl"? My favourite dictionary doesn't has that one…

Comment: @feeela it's an acronym for a **R**ead **E**val **P**rint **L**oop.

Comment: seems like your problem is that you expect `this` in the `on('exit'` function to be something it isn't.  Use a closure to capture the value of `this` in an outer scope and use that var instead of `this`.  I realize this is not the answer to your question, just saying.

Comment: thanks @SteveH. that is definitely an issue. But, that shouldn't matter in terms of having `repl` block, right?

Comment: Yeah that's why I didn't answer but mentioned in a comment :)